# How to persist Preference objects using a custom data store instead of using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, datastore, user-preferences

I have been working on a pet project where I initially used `SharedPreferences` to persist settings `Preference` objects. I decided to migrate it to use `data store` instead of `SharedPreferences`.

So I started with the `ListPreference` for the dark theme configuration. It worked fine as expected but the `ListPreference` keep reverting to its default value (`system_default_theme`) whenever the theme configuration changes.

For instance, when I select `dark_theme` from the `ListPreference` dialog, the app switches to dark theme and the activity is destroyed as well as the preference fragment. Whenever the fragment is recreated, the `ListPreference` displays the default value which is `system_default_theme` instead of `dark_theme`.

The app remains in `dark_theme` while the `ListPreference` shows `system_default_theme` as selected. More like the selection is lost or reverted on configuration change or when the fragment is destroyed. It seems the selection in the UI no longer reflects the stored preference value.

My last resort right now is to just get rid of the `XML` and just use `Jetpack Compose` instead.

I used `Proto DataStore`.

The `ListPreference` in **settings.xml**:

```
<ListPreference
            android:entries="@array/entries_theme"
            android:icon="@drawable/device_theme"
            android:key="key_dark_mode"
            android:summary="Turn on/off dark mode."
            android:title="Dark mode"
            app:defaultValue="system_default"
            app:entryValues="@array/entry_value_theme"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
```

Here's the implementation of the custom `data store` in the `onCreatePreferences()` of **SettingsPreferenceFragment.kt** :

```
findPreference<ListPreference>("key_dark_mode")
                                ?.apply {
                                    preferenceDataStore = object : PreferenceDataStore() {
                                        
                                        override fun putString(key: String?, value: String?) {
                                            val darkThemeConfig = 
                                                value?.getDarkThemeConfig() ?: DarkThemeConfig.FOLLOW_SYSTEM
                                            settingsViewModel.updateDarkThemeConfig(darkThemeConfig)
                                        }

                                        override fun getString(key: String?,defValue: String?): String? {
                                            return settingsUiState.settings.darkThemeConfig.getDarkMode()
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
```

Theme entries and values `string arrays`:

```
    <!-- theme entries array -->
    <string-array name="entries_theme">
        <item>Light mode</item>
        <item>Dark mode</item>
        <item>Use device settings</item>
    </string-array>
    <!-- theme entry values array -->
    <string-array name="entry_value_theme">
        <item>light_mode</item>
        <item>dark_mode</item>
        <item>system_default</item>
    </string-array>
```

Thanks in advance for your helpful answers. :)